# Proper Way to Generate An AJAX Endpoint in OctoberCMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, octobercms

I've used the default AJAX framework in OctoberCMS, but now I am trying to use something a bit more customized by creating a map that queries my server for more markers when it is panned. For this I need to define an endpoint such as

```
/markers
```

I know I can create a page to do this, but this seems messy since the default in OctoberCMS is to use a function of the format

```
onPan()
```

My current javascript function is:

```
var markerStore = {};

function getMarkers() {

    $.get('/markers', {}, function(res,resp) {
        for(var i=0, len=res.length; i<len; i++) {

            //Do we have this marker already?
            if(markerStore.hasOwnProperty(res[i].id)) {
                markerStore[res[i].id].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(res[i].position.lat,res[i].position.long));
            } else {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(res[i].position.lat,res[i].position.long),
                    title:res[i].name,
                    map:map
                }); 
                markerStore[res[i].id] = marker;
            }
        }
        window.setTimeout(getMarkers,INTERVAL);
    }, "json");
}
```

Is there someway that I can adjust this to use the default AJAX framework in OctoberCMS? If not, what is the appropriate way to create this page?

Answer (score 0):

OctoberCMS has its own AJAX library, for using this you need to create method in controller as you said `onPan()`

But what you can do is create a **routes.php** in plugin's root directory, i.e if plugin name is blog, so create routes.php file in blog folder, and use laravel`s routes same as other routes.

```
Route::get('markers',function(){
    // Use database of any computation to return markers 

});
```

Now you can access www.example.com/markers and use it as Native AJAX call with jQuery AJAX method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajaxframeworks js api: (https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api#javascript-api)

```
$.request('componentName::onGetMarkers', {
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```